# How to get the color of some element in Vim and apply it to another element

Tags: vim, colors, color-scheme, line-numbers

This is probably a strange question, but I'm trying to change the **current line number** in Vim to something different from all other numbers in the **line number column**.

Thing is, I don't want to change it to a specific value, but **to the value of some other gui element**.

For instance, change the line number colors to the ones of TabLineSel element:

```
TabLineSel     xxx term=bold ctermfg=2 ctermbg=10 guifg=#859900 guibg=#073642
```

How can I do this in Vim?

Answer (score 0):

Type

```
:highlight
```

in Vim. It will show you all the currently defined group with the color/rendering next to it.

I am not sure which one you want to change but I think you are looking to change either the `CursorLineNr` (only the number) or the `CursorLine` (the whole line) group.

To find out in which file it is defined :

```
:verbose hightlight CursorLineNr
```

Modify the file, copy paste the line next to `TabLineSel` and relauch VIm.

Comment: Isn't there any way to do this directly in `.vimrc` without changing the theme color file? Actually I have an idea on how to change `CursorLineNr`, what I don't know is how to get the values from `TabLineSel` in my `.vimrc`

Comment: I believe you can add the line in your .vimrc with `highlight CursorLine clear`followed by `highlight CursorLine XXX`. If you put it after the colorscheme selection it will override it.

Comment: Yes, that part I know. But how do I get, for instance, the value of the `TabLineSel guifg` property in my .vimrc? Perhaps it's not clear, but the idea is to be able to do something like: `highlight CursorLine XXX guifg=TabLineSel(guifg)` in my `.vimrc`

Comment: Look at the `:help hlID` and `:help synIDattr`, it seems you can get the syntax string associated with a highlight group.